# How can I use test nodes in rostest which are not part of rostest itself?

Tags: catkin, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to test a ROS node with [rostest](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest) but with a test node which is not included in `rostest` itself. Means instead of using the [hztest test node](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest/Nodes#hztest) like in this [rostest test](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/tools/rostest/test/hztest.test)...

```
<launch>
  <node name="talker" pkg="rospy" type="talker.py" />

  <param name="hztest1/topic" value="chatter" />  
  <param name="hztest1/hz" value="10.0" />
  <param name="hztest1/hzerror" value="0.5" />
  <param name="hztest1/test_duration" value="5.0" />    
  <param name="hztest1/wait_time" value="21.0" />    
  <test test-name="hztest_test" pkg="rostest" type="hztest" name="hztest1" />
</launch>
```

... I would like to use my own test node `owntest` from my own ROS Python package `ownpackage` instead:

```
<launch>
  <node name="talker" pkg="rospy" type="talker.py" />

  <param name="owntest1/topic" value="chatter" />  
  ...
  <param name="owntest1/test_duration" value="5.0" />    
  <test test-name="owntest_test" pkg="ownpackage" type="owntest" name="owntest1" />
</launch>
```

I built and installed `ownpackage` with `catkin_make --pkg ownpackage`, `cd /build/ownpackage` and `make install`.
However if I run the test I get an error because `rostest` does not know about the existence of `owntest`:

```
FAILURE: Test Fixture Nodes ['owntest'] failed to launch
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/florian/ws_catkin/src/ros_comm/tools/rostest/src/rostest/runner.py", line 121, in fn
    self.assert_(not failed, "Test Fixture Nodes %s failed to launch"%failed)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 422, in assertTrue
    raise self.failureException(msg)
```

How can I let `rostest` know about the existence of the `owntest` node from `ownpackage` that `rostest` can use it in a test?

Or alternativelly: What is the best approach/development procedure when I would place `owntest` into [ros_comm/rostest/nodes](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/lunar-devel/tools/rostest/nodes) instead of into `ownpackage`?

---

Edit: If I start the `roscore` and try to run a `rostest` test node with `rosrun rostest hztest` I got the following output:

```
[ROSUNIT] Outputting test results to /home/kromer/.ros/test_results/rostest/rosunit-hztest.xml
test_hz ... FAILURE!
FAILURE: hztest not initialized properly. Parameter ['~hz'] not set. debug[/hztest] debug[/hztest/hz]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 331, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/rostest/nodes/hztest/hztest", line 89, in test_hz
    self.fail('hztest not initialized properly. Parameter [%s] not set. debug[%s] debug[%s]'%(str(e), rospy.get_caller_id(), rospy.resolve_name(e.args[0])))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 412, in fail
    raise self.failureException(msg)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------
SUMMARY:
 * RESULT: FAIL
 * TESTS: 1
 * ERRORS: 0 []
 * FAILURES: 1 [test_hz]
```

I would expect the same for my package. I diff the files of my package and `rostest` to figure out what I missed...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272493/how-can-i-use-test-nodes-in-rostest-which-are-not-part-of-rostest-itself?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2017-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-07**:
This should work if you can run `owntest` with `rosrun`. Try `rosrun ownpackage owntest`

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-09**:
If I run `rosrun rosfake faketopicpublisherint32.test` I get the error `[rospack] Error: package 'rosfake' not found` not found`. Seems like I missed or messed up something in the package definition of the [package](https://github.com/fkromer/rosfake).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-09**:
@thinwybk: please only use answers to answer your own question. For everything else, use comments or edit your original question text.

I've already merged your update into your OP, but please keep it in mind for next time.

Thanks.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-09**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for the hint. I will consider that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for that stupid question. I just forgot to make `owntest` executable with `chmod +x owntest`.

---

Originally posted by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) with karma: 468 on 2017-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0